Using KingswaySoft JSON Destination component, how do you make one node of the prepared request repeatable and the other node not?
I am using Visual Studio 2022 to develop SSIS 2022 packages, creating a data flow from an OLEDB source (SQL Server query) into a KingswaySoft JSON Destination to post to a data entry endpoint. The request body has two nodes, a "where" node and a "do" node in 1 to many relationship.
My source query has 10 rows, so my "do" node will have 10 entries with a single "where" node as a wrapper. I set the Merge Mode to Buffer, but my "where" node is repeating in Preview and runtime. I want to toggle "Is Repeated" for the "where" node to False but the entire tree is disabled. How can I toggle repeating of the node off?


From the document design, when imported and tested, as long as the Root -> LinkId remains the same value as what is coming in from the Source, the JSON structure that gets created will only have one parent node (Where). The Array “Added” within the child “do” node will repeat inside the JSON object.

In our example, there’s one Root input with a specific linkId and other details, as well as multiple child inputs with the same root.linkid pointing to the unique parent linkId. Hope this helps!

